# Can anyone share documented steps to launch OpenStack nodes as VMs

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, openstack, kvm, devstack

I would like to set up a simple controller/compute OpenStack setup with controller node in one VM and compute as other, preferably created using KVM. I may look at adding more compute VM's later. Can anyone share any documented steps for the same?

I'm currently using Openstack training labs (out of the box install), however, I would like some documented steps to have a customized setup.

Comment: Also you may want to look into `packstack`: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Packstack#Packstack

Answer (score 0):

You can use devstack. Refer to the following link for more details, steps of installation are fairly straightforward.

https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/single-machine.html